# sales vs profit in percent

Tags: sql

I want only those columns where the difference between sales and profit is greater than 20 % in sql.

I want the difference in percentage .. For Example the sales value is 100 and the sold value is 120, then the profit is 20 % ... I want that in the query
sum(sales - profit ) > 20 % ?

can someone please help me with this query ?

Comment: what you have in your table columns and their types?

Comment: in the table there are many columns but there is category sales and profit. All are varchar

Comment: Update your question to explain well what you want and add what you just replied in comment there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about math:

```
Select * from YOURTABLE where ((sold - sales)/sales) > 0.2
```

Your `sales` and `sold` column should of a numeric type not `VARCHAR`